# How to use DTCoreText (DTWillFlushBlockCallBack) in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c-blocks, dtcoretext

```
        let callBackBlock:(DTHTMLElement) -> Void = { element in
        for oneChildElement in element.childNodes {
            guard let oneChildElement: DTHTMLElement = oneChildElement as? DTHTMLElement else {
                return
            }
            if oneChildElement.displayStyle == .inline && oneChildElement.textAttachment.displaySize.height > 2.0 * oneChildElement.fontDescriptor.pointSize {
                oneChildElement.displayStyle = .block;
                oneChildElement.paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = element.textAttachment.displaySize.height;
                oneChildElement.paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = element.textAttachment.displaySize.height;
            }
        }
    }
    let maxImageSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.size.width - 20, height: view.bounds.size.height - 20)
    return [NSTextSizeMultiplierDocumentOption: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1.0),
                                                DTMaxImageSize: NSValue(cgSize: maxImageSize),
                                                DTDefaultTextColor: UIColor.white,
                                                DTDefaultFontSize: NSNumber(floatLiteral: 15.0),
                                                DTWillFlushBlockCallBack: callBackBlock]
```

i use block in swift like this, but the block crashed with exc_bad_access

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder to generate attributedString like this

```swift
    let options = [String: Any]() # other options
    let callBack: (DTHTMLElement?) -> Void = { element in
      #do something
      print(element)
    }
    if let builder = DTHTMLAttributedStringBuilder(html: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) {  
      builder.willFlushCallback = callBack
      if let attribute = builder.generatedAttributedString() {
        print(attribute)
      }
    }
```